# How to deploy to Tomcat a multi maven module from Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a multi module Maven project with a common module which is a dependency of 2 others modules. One of this module generate a war which is integrated in the other one by overlay.

The final war is generated by Maven clean install command without problem. All the structure in target is OK.
But if I install a Tomcat 8 server in servers view (with 'takes Tomcat control installation' mode) and deploy the project, it's a nightmare...

I have tests resources in `WEB-INF/classes`, the common module (jar) is not deployed in `WEB-INF/lib`, the war which should be integrated during the build by overlay appears in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Is there a way to have a clean deployment without adding a Tomcat plugin in Maven configuration ?

For information, it is Neon version. 
Deployment assembly are configured with `src/main/*` only (plus Maven dependencies).

We don't understand why Eclipse doesn't deploy the final application generated in `target/xxx` directory.

Comment: Wait, do you have many `war` files in a big `war`? Maybe this is the issue. Either you go with `war` modularity, or you go with `jar` modularity. But not a chimera of both...

Comment: Yeah not my choice. We have recovered a old project where there is a War module which is overlapped in the final war. This functionality exists with Maven and no problem when we build with Maven. We tried with another classic projet, same pb with Eclipse (no project facet, no deployment assembly). Seems not the first time Eclipse can't manage the project. It's boring. Why doesn't he deployed the final target build ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

Eclipse doesn't care about Deployment Assembly.
It mix Deployment Assembly AND Java Build Path.

When you import a maven project, the configuration of your project can be bad for an unknown reason.
Check the sources folders declared in Java Build Path and check specialy the output directory of each source folder.

For `src/test/resources`, it set a default output (not `target/test-classes`). So all tests resources were copied into `target/classes`. 
And I don't know why he deployed to Tomcat this directory.

In Deployment Assembly, it just set these directories :

```
   - src/main/java -> WEB-INF/classes
   - src/main/webapp -> /
   - /target/m2e-wtp/web-resources -> /
   - Maven dependencies -> WEB-INF/lib
   - link to others modules
```

Now all work perfectly.